# use Reactive Extensions (Rx) but can't Found System.Observable.DLL File in Windows phone Application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, reactive-programming

well.
i was use Reactive Extensions (Rx) package async Request,Before you can start writing code you need to include the two dll’s required for reactive programming in Windows Phone.

it was:

using Microsoft.Phone.Reactive
using System.Observable

But i can't found System.Observable.DLL file in 。Net Framework 4?
anybody have some suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The references you need should be installed with the Windows Phone SDK. If you select "Add Reference" in a Windows Phone project you should see System.Observable and Microsoft.Phone.Reactive in the .NET tab. It's important you reference these assemblies as they match the ones already installed on the phone and therefore reducing the size of your application.

Comment: thank for your reply nigle. this question is solved。 i have been found Reactive Extensions[RX] Framework.But i didn't know how to use it .Can any one please suggest me  how to learn the technique？did you have any idea？ thanks